# mysql_fetch_array() not spiting anything

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$campagin_id = $_SESSION['campagin_id_for_camp'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM survey_result where campagin_id = ".$campagin_id;

$conn=mysql_connect($dbconfig['db_hostname'],$dbconfig['db_username'],$dbconfig['db_password']) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbconfig['db_name'],$conn);

$exec_query =mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_query);
echo "<br> row = ".$row;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_query)){
    echo "I am In";

}
```

The Problem is that I am not getting anything in `$row` I cant get into the while loop, nothing shows up when I try to `echo` the value of `$row`, No error Nothing. Can you help me to find a problem in my code ?

Ps : The database is their. I have checked for the query for the corresponding value of `$campagin_id`. and also when i tried to echo `$exec_query` it echoed this : **Resource id #8**

PPS : The database have more than 7 record for each id so it doesn't matter if I call mysql_fetch_array($exec_query) more than once before going in to the while loop. and for the `$campagin_id` in the session their are many records present in the database.

Comment: `$_SESSION['campagin_id_for_camp']` is a string or number?

Comment: @MuthuKumaran It is a Number

Comment: If you get I am in string then you have correctly executed your query.
If you want to fetch the entire row that you get from you id: then try this
`while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_query)){
    echo $row['column_name_you_want'];`

Comment: @TNC I dont go in to the while loop. That is the problem.

Comment: @HussainNagri - let me know what exactly you want to `echo`. So i can help you. And check my answer.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: @HussainNagri try the code in my answer. Also see the point about calling `fetch_array()` twice.

Comment: @HussainNagri - are you getting the value of session?? have you tried echoing `$query`?? try echoing it and run it in mysql database to see if you are getting any results or not... !!

Answer (score 3):

You have written `$row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_query)` and then you are `echo`ing something. and you are using the same in while.

Instead of:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_query);
echo "<br> row = ".$row;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_query)){
    echo "I am In";
}
```

Use this (as per my knowledge you should not use `$row=mysql_fetch_array()` once you have used before while):

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_query)){
    echo "I am In";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the query returns `Resource id #8` then that means it was successful - ie there were no errors. There were probably no rows returned by that query, so no rows in your table that match the given `campagin_id`.

You are also calling `mysql_fetch_array()` twice separately, you shouldn't do that because your while loop will skip the first row because calling this moves the pointer in the result set forward by one.

Also you can't echo an array as you are trying to, if you want to see the contents of an array use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

I suggest adding some code to handle no rows found:

```
if($exec_query && mysql_num_rows($exec_query) > 0)
{
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_query)){
        echo "Row: " . print_r($row, true);
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'None found';
}
```

Comment: No, I tried to run the code with an ID that exist but nothing. with your code in it it showed None found.

Comment: That means there's no rows that match the ID that you passed. You need to echo out the `$query` SQL to see what ID you are passing, then check it in a DB tool such as phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I did that already. The query has a id that DO EXIST in the database and the query works fine when ran in MySQL directly. Query is not the issue.

Comment: Verify that you are looking at the correct database and table.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
<?
$campagin_id = $_SESSION['campagin_id_for_camp'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM survey_result where campagin_id = ".$campagin_id;

mysql_connect($dbconfig['db_hostname'],$dbconfig['db_username'],$dbconfig['db_password']) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbconfig['db_name']);

$exec_query =mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_query)) {
    echo "<br/> row = <pre>".print_r($row)."</pre><br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: -1, you have not explained what you changed, why you changed it, how the changes work, and how this solves the problem stated in the OP.

Comment: Echoing it with some html tags wont make any difference. would it ?

Comment: It's not only echoing, but also rewritten that code to be more short. also removed some pieces of unrequired code. If this code doesn't work, then the only reason is query returns no result.